# Remote Red Hat Session Black Screen

Tags: redhat, remote-desktop

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Workstation 7.6, up until today I had been logging in via my Windows 10 laptop to this remote workstation daily without issues for many months. My coworkers are still able to, but now all I get is a black screen after entering my credentials and it eventually disconnects me. No updates have been applied to either machine and no (intentional) configure changes were made to my user, which this issue seems to confined to.

I have tried many things suggested such as lowering the resolution, disabling bitmap caching, rebooted both my laptop and the RH workstation without luck. I can SSH in no problem but cannot RDP in.

I am all out of ideas, able to remote in this morning then had to log out (no changes were made to anything to my knowledge) and now I can't log in. I am not sure what additional info to provide but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: Anything specific I should be looking for? This isn't my area of expertise

Comment: .xsession-errors is indeed a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue, the .xsessions-errors file in my home directory had a single entry in it, the entry was a line echoed at the end of my .bashrc file. It didn't give an error or anything just this line which made me suspect the .bashrc file. Remember that I had added a line to is before this started happening I removed that line and voila, I am able to start an RDP session again.